# How to extract comma separated values to individual rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my dataframe (where the values in the authors column are comma separated strings):

```
authors            book
Jim, Charles       The Greatest Book in the World
Jim                An OK book
Charlotte          A book about books
Charlotte, Jim     The last book
```

How do I transform it to a long format, like this:

```
authors            book
Jim                The Greatest Book in the World
Jim                An OK book
Jim                The last book
Charles            The Greatest Book in the World
Charlotte          A book about books
Charlotte          The last book
```

I've tried extracting the individual authors to a list, `authors = list(df['authors'].str.split(','))`, flatten that list, matched every author to every book, and construct a new list of dicts with every match. But that doesn't seem very pythonic to me, and I'm guessing pandas has a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can split the authors column by column after setting the index to the book which will get you almost all the way there. Rename and sort columns to finish.

```py
df.set_index('book').authors.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index('book')

                             book          0
0  The Greatest Book in the World        Jim
1  The Greatest Book in the World    Charles
0                      An OK book        Jim
0              A book about books  Charlotte
0                   The last book  Charlotte
1                   The last book        Jim
```

And to get you all the way home

```py
df.set_index('book')\
  .authors.str.split(',', expand=True)\
  .stack()\
  .reset_index('book')\
  .rename(columns={0:'authors'})\
  .sort_values('authors')[['authors', 'book']]\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

- The best option is to use [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and then to [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the `list`.

  - Split on `', '`, otherwise values following the comma will be preceded by a whitespace (e.g. `' Charles'`)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'authors': ['Jim, Charles', 'Jim', 'Charlotte', 'Charlotte, Jim'], 'book': ['The Greatest Book in the World', 'An OK book', 'A book about books', 'The last book']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
          authors                            book
0    Jim, Charles  The Greatest Book in the World
1             Jim                      An OK book
2       Charlotte              A book about books
3  Charlotte, Jim                   The last book

# split authors
df.authors = df.authors.str.split(', ')

# explode the column (with a fresh 0, 1... index)
df = df.explode('authors', ignore_index=True)

# display(df)
     authors                            book
0        Jim  The Greatest Book in the World
1    Charles  The Greatest Book in the World
2        Jim                      An OK book
3  Charlotte              A book about books
4  Charlotte                   The last book
5        Jim                   The last book
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!