# Pyspark: Is there a function to split dataframe column values on the basis of comma

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

input

```
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|ID            |Subject                |Marks                  |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1             |maths,physics          |80,90                  |
|2             |Computer               |73                     |
|3             |music,sports,chemistry |76,89,85               |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Expected output

```
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|ID            |Subject                |Marks                  |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1             |maths                  |80                     |
|1             |physics                |90                     |
|2             |Computer               |73                     |
|3             |music                  |76                     |
|3             |sports                 |89                     |
|3             |chemistry              |85                     |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

**need help in getting this expected output**
,*have already tried explode function but that only works on single column*

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539765/how-to-extract-each-value-in-a-column-of-comma-separated-strings-into-individual/63538353#63538353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way;, split the columns on `,` to form arrays. Zip the arrays and leverage pysparks' inline function to achieve what you want

```
df.withColumn('Subject', split(col("Subject"),",")).withColumn('Marks', split(col("Marks"),",")).selectExpr('ID','inline(arrays_zip(Subject,Marks))')

+---+---------+-----+
| ID|  Subject|Marks|
+---+---------+-----+
|  1|    maths|   80|
|  1|  physics|   90|
|  2| Computer|   73|
|  3|    music|   76|
|  3|   sports|   89|
|  3|chemistry|   85|
+---+---------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @wwnde
it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` multiple columns at once:

```
cols = ['Subject', 'Marks']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(','))
df.explode(cols)
```

Output:

```
   ID    Subject Marks
0   1      maths    80
0   1    physics    90
1   2   Computer    73
2   3      music    76
2   3     sports    89
2   3  chemistry    85
```